# Combine rest spread and default value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know I can use rest spread to make any number of function arguments available as a named array:

```js
function logArgs(...args) {
  console.log(args);
}

logArgs(1, "a", {});
```

For specified function parameters, it is also possible to define a default value right in the function signature:

```js
function logA(a = 1) {
  console.log(a);
}

logA();
logA(2);
```

**Question:** Why does using *both* throw a `Rest parameter may not have a default initializer` error?

```js
function logArgs(...args = [1]) {
  console.log(args);
}

logArgs(1, "a", {});
logArgs();
```

Comment: maybe this answer could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/42650963/2860519