# Either Array or undefined or default array as argument to function

Tags: arrays, typescript, function, overloading

I want to pass optionally an array to a function or an array setting it to a default value.

This is the typical way:
`function myfunc(...values : Array<number>)`

I know that I can do it this way, but I don't know how to set it to allow this function calls:

```js
myfunc()
myfunc(1)
myfunc(1,2)
myfunc([1, 2])
```

with the above, all except myfunc() are supported. How can I make it?

Comment: Can we see the function declaration you already have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your two overloads and then specify the logic in a single function. Something like below should work.

```ts
function myfunc(...values : Array<number>): number;
function myfunc(values : Array<number>): number;

function myfunc(value : (Array<number> | number), ...values : Array<number>): number {
    if (typeof value === 'number') {
        values.unshift(value);
    } else if (value === undefined) {
        values = [];
    } else {
        values = value;
    }

    // logic

    return values.length;
}

myfunc(); // correct
myfunc(1); // correct
myfunc(1, 2); // correct
myfunc([1, 2]); // correct
myfunc(1, 2, 3, 4); // correct
myfunc([1, 2, 3]); // correct
// myfunc([1, 2, 3, 4], 5, 6); // error
// myfunc([1, 2], [3, 4]); // error

console.log(myfunc(1, 2, 3)) // 3
console.log(myfunc([1, 2, 3])) // 3
```

Notice how because we have not defined an interface for an array followed by values, the final example results in an error which I think is the expected behaviour. An example can be seen [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ6kgCgHS4G4CGANiAKYDOiAXIgIIBO9BqAPGCMgEan0B8AlDXZceAbgBQGaPCRopmQiQrU6jZmw7c+gxMK0TJ4aQhTojC4mRWYGTVnp69EAH12ae-ADSJc2RWUoaW3UHbSF3ekQAb3FEOMQYYERMKFQAB1I4JP9SRABeAsQAclCi-mjY+Kqc8mxwcgALRKgLJX4JKoBfRFIiclzE5Jz8wvAAE1JgGDBSMfKYqurLZTzEAG0AXQ747t7+isX4mvzEHO24zvFKuIB6G8QiOABzGAgrqvpSKBB6JBrsIikMBPKANCSXcRycztRB3RAQOCMUjQSFmLAARhhcIRSJRUIx3gATFj7jjPni0RBMGt0USNiT4YjyVBUfJaYhCd4AMzeAAsDLJyJZ+KpNKJ3PpolhpKZQvEcJF1PZnMQPMQvI23gArN4AGwMnj0RHy+6KsUczXrNUag2MY3iBFgchwQEA56YRXK7n8cpwrkOhDO12PJ4eylK8Wq+m++5coA). We have to check for undefined here as the transpiled JavaScript does not take into account the different function overloads, and instead provides a single implementation where `value` can be undefined.

Comment: I like explicit way of function overrides, because it's more like documentation and it makes you think about multiple logic flows.

Comment: So there is no way of using the ? operator like `...value?` ?

Comment: Not for your desired behaviour as `?` denotes that undefined is allowed

Comment: And what about if I set a default value? let's say that value can be [ 0 ] as default. Then would it be possible? could you please give a hint in case it is.

Comment: Unfortunately, a rest parameter cannot have a default value. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650594/is-it-possible-to-set-default-parameter-value-on-a-rest-parameter) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```js
function myfunc(...values : Array<number> | [Array<number>]) {}

myfunc()
myfunc(1)
myfunc(1,2)
myfunc([1, 2])

myfunc('invalid')
myfunc([1, 2], [3, 4])
```

Here is a [preview](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ6kgCgHS4G4CGANiAKYDOiAXIgIIBO9BqAPGCMgEan0B8iAH0QBtBk1bsuPXgF0AlIgDeAXwBQqtBgiY5G9OG0BGXZoOZDAGgBMJ-VmGXEV+etNYA5DDCEiMACbutlqYDhZOMmHCAMxhACwuQA) where you can check the result.

Comment: Doesn't this make `myfunc([1, 2], [3, 4])` valid which is not intended behaviour?

Comment: @Hive7 Right. I've updated the answer to fix it.

Comment: It still doesn't work quite as you would expect, since the type inside the implementation is confused between a singleton array and an array of values. Consider myfunc([1, 2, 3, 4]), the function treats it as [[1, 2, 3, 4]] which is not what is desired here

Answer (score -2):

Can you use like this in a simple way !!!

```
function a(k = []) {
    console.log(k)
}

a();
a(1);
a([1]);
a([1, 2, 3]);
```

Comment: When I try this code on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play, it gives lots of errors...

Comment: @PeterB, I have written the above code in Js, not in Ts. If you want to run the same code in TS,  please change the function to ,  function a(k:any=null) {
    console.log(k)
}