# Overloaded return type not properly working

Tags: typescript, return, overloading

Following [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554937/either-array-or-undefined-or-default-array-as-argument-to-function) I'm now facing a problem with return type overloading.

```
interface A {
  a: number,
  b: string
}

function myFunc(...sIs: Array<number>): Map<number, A[]>;
function myFunc(sIs: Array<number>): Map<number, A[]>;
function myFunc(s: Array<number> | number, ...sIs: Array<number>): A | Map<number, A[]> {

}
```

I'm overloading the function so when only one parameter (i.e. `myFunc(1)`), the return value is a single data ¿or undefined?, while if the input is an Array it returns a Map based the function arguments.

The problem I'm facing is `Conversion of type 'Map<number, A[]>' to type 'A' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.`

If I don't include undefined as a potential return value, I have managed to solve the problem by:

```
const info: any = await myFunc(5);
const snfo: A = info as A;
```

But if I include the return value like `A | Map<number, A[]> | undefined` there is no way of doing it. I know the simple way would be to always return a `Map`, but I want to learn how to properly do it.

Comment: What is `<Map<number, A[]>` (the return type annotation on the first signature) meant to mean? Also, your implementation signature has `A` as one of its possible return types, but neither of your overloads does...?

Comment: The return types of your overloads do not match the return type of your implementation. One of them must return A or your implementation must only return the map type.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I fixed it... it was a typo

Comment: @Silvermind That's the point. I want to return A in case the input arguments is just a singular number, but a Map in case the input argument is an array or a sequence of numbers. Is this possible?

Comment: Where does the value of `b` come from?

Comment: @jlanza The two answers provided, at the time of writing this, exactly explain my point.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It is something that is filled inside the function. I haven't included the whole example.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment you've said:

> I want to return `A` in case the input arguments is just a singular number, but a `Map` in case the input argument is an array or a sequence of numbers.

So let's write each of those separately. Accepting a number and returning an `A`:

```typescript
// First signature
function myFunc(x: number): A;
```

Accepting an array of numbers and returning a `Map<number, A>` (I assume you mean `Map<number, A>`, not `Map<number, A[]>` which would be a map mapping numbers to **arrays** of `A`):

```typescript
// Second signature
function myFunc(x: number[]): Map<number, A>;
```

And finally, accepting any number of discrete `number` arguments and returning `Map<number, A>`. Normally you'd write that like this:

```typescript
// (Probably won't use this one, keep reading)
function myFunc(...x: number[]): Map<number, A>;
```

...but because we already have signatures where `x` is `number` or `number[]`, having that signature might make the implementation complicated, so let's use this instead:

```typescript
// Third signature
function myFunc(x: number, ...y: number[]): Map<number, A>;
```

Now we have to write the implementation signature, which is just the three above combined:

```typescript
// Implementation signature
function myFunc(x: number | number[], ...y: number[]): A | Map<number, A>
```

All together, with a sample implementation:

```typescript
interface A {
    a: number,
    b: string
}

function myFunc(x: number): A;
function myFunc(x: number[]): Map<number, A>;
function myFunc(...x: number[]): Map<number, A>;
function myFunc(x: number | number[], ...y: number[]): A | Map<number, A> {
    if (typeof x === "number") {
        if (y.length === 0) {
            // Just a single number was provided
            return makeA(x);
        }
        // Multiple discrete numbers
        x = [x, ...y];
    }
    return new Map(x.map(a => [a, makeA(a)]));
}
```

That supports all of the following:

```
myFunc(42);
myFunc([1, 2]);
myFunc(3, 4);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XALmRAFcBbAI2gBoc8KiBnMKUAcywF8ssYSQEYYAHsQyMgE8AYvwQAKAB5FSlaAEoiqANy9ZQ0eOmzFy8lSgBtALobkAWTgAHADwrz1NAD4dfAfrGSMgJyAHRhSsRm0Na2Di5uNF4+eiIBRsERCVDIAD6RqpZWHmEhEqYFMZq59k6uUVAeqJ6YdLjAMMhyYBKOEMIdCsgAvCPIAERZY2oteLPI7Z0SIQA2ECBsYAAWw6MADNPYc0fIAPQnyABSJMz4yIzsq-nmyADucIzIjlDCAG7AACYQf6tY64KAQMAkKABOAAawgqEUah0oO4oLO9hIyyEjke-2AjAQ4MgT2gjBBs0GQ2QFgUxTCEisKLwaLwxKhYhAEBeNUcihCZCccjgw2aFjgHkF8MRcDUNmRXB4vkEqXEcIRwvK5ls6EOyHZ0MwEuQDGQAANmKx1sgYMJsgASDBwThmzg6bhYBCiRjCVYrYRsOSBYwAFgATGoFRinURwx5TWNLewbXbkOGxh6vSAfX7lgGg+l5BYAIweMPynQYuLIfpYDHF0VGoilk1ERMsZO27LFjN185hxsx5Bh+NtpPWrvD3ue72+iD+wPB4IAZg8IcjlfO1drGOXg8IyFXrfG47YKeyy97GJD+9jo5PHYnqZDvaAA)

Answer (score 1):

You're not using function overloads correctly.

In short, functions should have one overload signature for each different way to use that function. And then the implementation must implement the superset of all possibilities from all overloads.

And what's important is that the implementation *is not callable.* Only the overload signatures may be directly called.

So a simple example:

```
function foo(val: number[]): number[]
function foo(val: number): number
function foo(val: number | number[]): number | number[] {
   return val
}

foo([1,2,3]) // [1,2,3], type is number[]
foo(1) // 1, type is number
```

---

So that means you do not have a function signature that accepts `number` as an argument, and returns `A`.

You want something closer to:

```
function myFunc(sIs: number[]): Map<number, A[]>;
function myFunc(sIs: number): A;

function myFunc(s: number[] | number): A | Map<number, A[]> {
  if (Array.isArray(s)) {
    // process array, return Map<number, A>
  } else {
    // process single value, return A
  }
}

const a = myFunc(1) // A
const b = myFunc([1,2,3]) // Map<number, A>
```

The first overload handles arrays, the second handles single values, and the implementation handles (and returns) both.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&module=1&allowSyntheticDefaultImports=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLgLmRAFcBbAI2gBodlzCBnMKUAcywF8ssZiQEwwAPYhkpAJ4AxPggAUDAJINCJCtADaAXQCUhALJwADgB5VlKFTRaAfAG4eMwSLFSZ8pSrLndaew-5OohLS-PKealBayAA+RF7QPuixBiZm1Faa1pi0wDDIsqhQUHDiAHTADIXF4vLa2tm4uAD0TciGUEJIDAx4RSWWUBBgxFCiKabxFmjWtLiDw6NEEADuyCmy9S3IACoA8gAiu4SIw3AANsjApIZnEKQQ4HCBtBzIEGcMKNiNyFvtnRBusgGGxbsgAG7nYgQAZDEaiVCzZDzeGYPCMSz0ZAAcjgwOYbGxyFeWz2h2OAmI50u11u90ez1wXC4WAQIiYeGQAF4XCE5ABGTatRFskAc8jc3ludT8qgAJioAGYdL9WuM0lNUNYgA)

---

Supporting multiple arguments `foo(1,2,3)` as an array does get trickier. But I would advise against it. It makes for a fairly clunky API, in my opinion.

Comment: The code you include in your explanation is similar to the one I have in mine. The problem is that when I call `const a = myFunc(1)` I get the error that I showed. I think the most wise solution would be to remove the option to have an array as multiple arguments. I will simplify the code as well.